# Getting MySQL values into an array from two different tables?

Tags: php, sql, mysql, arrays, tags

My tagging system uses two tables, `tags` and `coupon_tags`. The way it works is that each coupon and each tag is assigned a numerical value. So a coupon may have the id `13` and a tag may have the id `5`, for example. `coupon_tags` makes a new row per coupon per tag, so it may look like so:

```
couponID | tagID
    5        3
    5        1
    5        9
    6        1
```

In the code I am working on, the `couponID` is known, and represented as the variable `$coupID`. **I need help on the following:** So what I would have to do is figure out all of the rows where `couponID` is, and pull all of those `tagID`'s into an array, for example, `$allTagIDs[]`, and then loop through that array and at each iteration, match the `tagID` to a `tagName` in the next table called `tags` (both tables have a `tagID` field, which is how I match them up). Those tags need to be put into an array as well.

Then for output, I'll just `print_r($arrOfTagNames)`. I just don't know how to do what I wrote up there in PHP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't actually want to do that. You want to write ONE query which retrieves the names of the tags associated with coupon `$coupID`.

If you're ever running a query in a loop, you're probably doing something wrong, and it'll come back to bite you by overloading your server as soon as you have some significant traffic.

```
$sql = "
    SELECT
      tags.tagID,
      tags.tagName
    FROM
      tags
    INNER JOIN
      coupon_tags
    ON
      coupon_tags.tagID = tags.tagID
    WHERE
      coupon_tags.couponID = $coupID
";

$result = mysql_query($sql);

$arrOfTagNames = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  $arrOfTagNames[] = $row['tagName'];
}

print_r($arrOfTagNames);
```